# How can set post value and unset it by observer magento 2

Tags: php, magento2

I want to get data by current url so i have set post value, please see my code

```
if (currenturl = 'https://example.com/delhi.html') {
      $this->request->setPostValue('location','289');
}
```

But it set for all pages, i want to unset it if another url open. Please anyone idea for that

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
$this->request->setPostValue('location','');
if (currenturl = 'https://example.com/delhi.html') {
      $this->request->setPostValue('location','289');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but it is still set for another page. want to unset it if another page will open. please help me

Comment: one more thing you can do is update"location" value as empty after using lt.

Comment: $this->request->setPostValue('location','');
 if ($bb_currenturl = 'https://example.com/delhi.html') {
      $this->request->setPostValue('location','289');
} else {
  $this->request->setPostValue('location','');
}

like this

Comment: but it not removing from another page. is above code right